# Блок стрелка с использованием SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

Мне нужно нарисовать красивую заштрихованную стрелку блока, используя SVG из одной точки (x0, y0) в другую (x1, y1), как показано на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственный способ, который я могу себе представить, - это использовать линию (две линии в основном для имитации обводки и заливки) с маркером, но она выглядит некрасиво из-за перекрывающихся штрихов.

В идеале и линия, и маркер должны быть заполнены одинаковым цветом и иметь одинаковый цвет обводки, а общая ширина стрелки может быть фиксированной (но если бы я мог создать линию с помощью JS,изменяя параметры, это было бы круто).

По сути, он должен выглядеть так же, как на картинке.  Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 5):

Я написал функцию для генерации пути правильной формы.

Вам просто нужно указать координаты «от» и «до», ширину линии, ширину стрелки и длину стрелки.

```js
var from = {x: 50, y: 250};
var to = {x: 250, y: 100};

var lineWidth = 30;
var arrowheadWidth = 60;
var arrowheadLength = 50;

var svg = document.getElementById("test");

drawArrow(svg, from, to, lineWidth, arrowheadWidth, arrowheadLength);


function drawArrow(svg, from, to, lineWidth, arrowheadWidth, arrowheadLength)
{
  var dx = to.x - from.x;
  var dy = to.y - from.y;
  // Calculate the length of the line
  var len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (len < arrowheadLength) return;

  // Разница между шириной линии и шириной стрелки
  var dW = arrowheadWidth - lineWidth;
  // Угол наклона линии
  var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI;
 //Создайте путь, описывающий стрелку. Для простоты мы определяем это как
  //горизонтальная линия  длиной вправо, начиная с 0,0. Тогда мы поворачиваем
  // и перемещаем его на место с атрибутом преобразования.
  var d = ['M', 0, -lineWidth/2,
           'h', len - arrowheadLength,
           'v', -dW / 2,
           'L', len, 0,
           'L', len - arrowheadLength, arrowheadWidth / 2,
           'v', -dW / 2,
           'H', 0,
           'Z' ];
  var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  path.setAttribute("d", d.join(' '));
  path.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+from.x+","+from.y+") rotate("+angle+")");
  path.setAttribute("class", "arrow-line");
  svg.appendChild(path);
}
```

```css
.arrow-line {
  fill: gold;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 6;
}
```

```html
<svg id="test" width="300" height="300">
</svg>
```

[Источник:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743835/7394871) @Paul LeBeau

Answer (score 3):

Создана нормализованная стрелка в теге SVG `defs`.
Затем масштабируем стрелку после предоставленных координат. (Добавлена статическая высота XD)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var svgDoc = document.getElementById("arrowSvg");
  var useArrow = svgDoc.getElementById("customArrow");
  var extraData = useArrow.getAttribute("extra:data");
  extraData = extraData.split(" ");
  var x1 = parseInt(extraData[0]);
  var x2 = parseInt(extraData[1]);
  var y1 = parseInt(extraData[2]);
  var y2 = parseInt(extraData[3]);
  var arrowHeight = 15;
  //Calculate the rotation needed
  var deltaY = y1 - y2;
  var deltaX = x2 - x1;
  var angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * (180 / Math.PI);
  //Distance between the two points.
  var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
  useArrow.setAttribute("transform", 
                        "translate("+(x1+(deltaX/2))+" "+(y1-(deltaY/2))+") "+
                        "rotate(" + -1*angle +") " +
                        "matrix("+distance+", 0, 0, "+arrowHeight+", "+(0.5-distance*0.5)+","+(0.5-arrowHeight* 0.5)+")");

});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.arrow {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.05;
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg id="arrowSvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:extra="ExtraNameSpace">>
  <defs>
    <path id="idArrow" class="arrow" d="M0,0.25 0.60,0.25 
                         0.60,0 1,0.5 0.60,1
                         0.60,0.75 0,0.75z" />
  </defs>
  <!--- Extra Data Param: x1 x2 y1 y2--->
  <use id="customArrow" xlink:href="#idArrow" extra:data="10 90 90 5" />

</svg>
```

Источник [@Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41747656/7394871)